# Error condition is fixed still getting SIGSEGV in C

Tags: c, signals

In the following code, I am handling SIGSEGV signal and fixing the 
error condition by minimizing the bound variable. I guess whenever the signal handler returns it restarts the instruction during which the signal occurred. In signal handler I minimized the bound variable but still getting SIGSEGV and going in infinite loop

Not sure where I am going wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void SIG_segfault_handler(int);
static int  bound = 5800000;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGSEGV,SIG_segfault_handler);
    puts("This is the driver code for experimenting with signal");
    int *array = malloc(50);
    *(array+ 23) = 78;
    puts("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    *(array + bound) = 100;
    printf("Data: %d , %d \n",*(array + 23),*(array + bound));

    puts("Initialiazed array with 50 bytes.. \n End of driver code. ");
    //free(array);
    return 0;
}

void SIG_segfault_handler(int signum)
{
    puts("This is segmentation fault.. cannot continue with the memory operation.. aborting");
    puts("Signal SIGSEGV is handled by the program");   
    puts("Fixing the error conditions..");
    bound = 2;
}
```

Comment: `puts()` is not async-signal-safe and can't be safely called from a signal handler.  **Only** async-signal-safe functions can be called from a signal handler.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04

Comment: There's no guarantee that when you return from a signal handler, the instruction is restarted.  If anything, I'd expect the opposite.  But really, you can't depend on it either way.

Comment: Bottom line: this code will never work, there's no way to fix it.  Getting a segmentation violation is like breaking a raw egg: there's no way to pick up the pieces afterwards. (The only solution is to not have the segmentation violation / break the egg in the first place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *undefined behaviour* per C and POSIX standards. Returning from a signal handler of SIGSEGV is not allowed.

See [7.14.1.1 The signal function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p3):

> When a signal occurs and func points to a function, it is
>   implementation-defined whether the equivalent of signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
>   is executed or the implementation prevents some implementation-defined
>   set of signals (at least including sig) from occurring until the
>   current signal handling has completed; in the case of SIGILL, the
>   implementation may alternatively define that no action is taken. Then
>   the equivalent of (*func)(sig); is executed. If and when the function
>   returns, if the value of sig is SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, or any other
>   implementation-defined value corresponding to a computational
>   exception, the behavior is undefined; otherwise the program will
>   resume execution at the point it was interrupted.

After executing the signal handler, the execution restarts the same instruction which caused the SIGSEGV. That means when you overflow the array (which causes SIGSEGV) will be executed *again* after returning 
from the signal handler. This should explain the infinite loop.

Besides, you shouldn't call `puts()` from a signal signal handler; you are only allowed to call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler. See the [POSIX manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) for the list of async-signal-safe functions.

Use of `signal()` is also discouraged due to different semantics provided by various implementations. For this reason (among others), it's recommended to use [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) for installing signal handlers.